# Magento 2 order by product options

Tags: magento2, collection, custom-options, configurable-product-options

I am getting product options by using below code.

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
```

Now I want to sort them in `Desc` order so the last inserted will render first.

Is there anyway to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

well you basically are retrieving a collection, so you should be able to sort it as you wish, by using  `setOrder()`:

```php
$customOptionsCollection = clone customOptions;
$customOptionsCollection->setOrder(
    'option_id',
    'desc'
)
```

---

***sidenote*** you should avoid instantiation via object manager as it is a bad practice.

Comment: This is not working as the collection already sorting by title. I need to override the function.